# Same paint touch up noticeable

Tags: repainting

I've recently re decorated my spare room but there were some wet spots on one of the walls. I primed it as to prevent it from bleeding through and then painted over it.

You can see the different shade though and I tried painting over the entire wall and it's still slightly noticeable?

Any ideas?

I'm using a roller and I used a roller to begin with and
It's the exact same paint (Matte)

Comment: "Wet spots"? What are those? It would probably have been wise to prime the entire wall for consistency.

Comment: Basically, there was wallpaper on the walls so I took it all down, some parts wouldn't come off so I used fabric softener as advise to wet the paper. It came off but left water marks

Comment: Feather the edges of the patches with a roller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When touching up a wall, were the paint has fully cured. It's best to prime and paint (or just paint, were priming is not required) the entire wall, rather than touching up small spots.

You probably won't notice the small color difference between two adjoining walls. You will, however, notice a small blotch in the middle of a wall.

Comment: I primed the wall to cover up the water bleed. I guess I should have primed the entire wall. Is there any other way to cover it up? If I keep painting the wall would that work?

Comment: Prime the whole wall and paint it, that *should* fix it.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that when I have the extra money to buy the Primer